# Is it possible to declare a private function in an interface?

Tags: typescript

I am trying to setup an interface in Typescript that will be implemented (not extended from) and I want one of the functions to always be private.  Is this possible?

```
export interface ITabViewModel {
    isLoading: KnockoutObservable<boolean>;
    private setActiveTab(): void;
}

export class TabViewModel implements ITabViewModel {
    isLoading: KnockoutObservable<boolean>;
    private setActiveTab(){
        // DO SOMETHING HERE
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, an interface's members are always public.

Private functions are part of the implementation details and so it doesn't make sense to have private functions on an interface.

Comment: That is what I thought but wanted to make sure I was not missing something.

Comment: I also tried to set it to public in the interface then force it to private in the implementation, this failed as well.

Comment: @JasonH yeah, you can't make implemented functions private either. Think about this code if `setActiveTab` was in the interface, but marked as private in the implementation: `var myTabViewModel: ITabViewModel = new TabViewModel();` `myTabViewModel` is of type `ITabViewModel`. Now... should the following be an error? `myTabViewModel.setActiveTab();` That's why a private implementation isn't allowed... it wouldn't make sense.